# How to disable automatic brightness setting on LG monitors?

Tags: brightness, lg-monitor

I have two LG monitors (both 23MB35PM) which have an annoying and distracting feature of automatically changing their brightness at random times, probably due to some power saving mechanism.

How can I switch it off?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The option is not in the *main* menu, but has a dedicated button here:

[image]

Click the button enough times to select OFF.

Comment: On my monitor (23MP55) there was a "READER" button

Comment: @fpg1503 "READER" doesn't help in my 23MP55. The button next to it, "FUNC", has the function to disable auto brightness :)

Comment: READER solved it on my 24MP55.  Thank you @fpg1503

Comment: For my LG 32UP83A-W it did not have any button or menu item to disable this. For me I disabled HDR from my macbook pro display settings and it is not auto adjusting brightness till now, will update the comment if i see the problem again.

Answer (score 20):

I have the LG 24m45 and I was having the same issue.  I looked all over for the menu to change it, however it is actually in a special menu-which is an awful idea.  I found the separate menu by pressing down the function(FUNC./) key twice and the menu popped up.  Hop this fixes your problem!

Comment: +1 Also works on the LG 23MP55. Thanks!

Comment: UI horrible on that model - have you seen the navigation in the menu? Surely designed by electronic engineers. Nice monitor, though!

Comment: Same for 24EB23. Press "Func/>" button to get into a separate menu where you can disable the "power saving" stuff. I have 2 displays of the same model, one was constantly changing brightness, the other was not. It was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 14):

In my LG monitor, which I purchased a few weeks before, this feature (automatically changing the brightness once every while) was annoying.

I found that I can disable this feature by setting the following option:

Menu -> Settings -> General -> **Smart Energy saving** = OFF

Comment: Wow. It took me forever to figure this out. I was blaming the GPU before. Works on LG 32gk850.

Comment: The feature may also be called **DFC**.