# Change brightness on LG 22MP68VQ monitor

Tags: macos, display, multiple-monitors, brightness

I have two LG 22MP68VQ monitors connected to an iMac running macOS Sierra.

I want to dim the backlight on the monitors. I'm pretty sure you can't do it on a software level and have tried things like Shades and Brightness Slider.

I am fine doing it manually on the monitor. However, there doesn't seem to be an option for it.

There is a 'Display' button in the settings menu but it is greyed out. I'm pretty sure that's how to change the brightness but I can't understand why it won't let me access this menu.

Can someone please help with this because these screens are very bright at night time.

Comment: Are you certain software level doesn't work?  Have you tried [EasyMCC](https://bluesky-soft.com/en/EasyMCC.html)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](http://www.lg.com/uk/support/support-product/lg-22MP68VQ-P#) you may need to change the Picture Mode to Custom before you can enter the Display subsection:

[image: Picture menu]

However it appears the correct place to change brightness is under Quick Settings:
[image: Quick Settings menu]

If that still doesn't help, it seems like a few other people have issues with the SMART ENERGY SAVING mode automatically adjusting brightness.  I would recommend turning this OFF (shown under the Quick Settings section in the screenshot above).
  If you don't have that option, [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/842678/how-to-disable-automatic-brightness-setting-on-lg-monitors) details how to disable it via a hardware button.